# The security token included in the request is expired when using ProfileCredentialsProvider

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, guice, aws-credentials

I am connecting to SQS through my Java code, and the connection is required to be alive for more than 60 minutes, as I keep polling a queue for a long time. However the credentials I use seem to expire. How can I keep the credentials alive?

Below is how I create the credentials provider:

```
@Provides
    public AwsCredentialsProvider getSTSCredentialProvider() {
        final String credentialsPath = System.getenv("CREDENTIAL_PATH");

        final AwsCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.builder().profileFile(
                ProfileFile.builder().content(Paths.get(credentialsPath)).type(ProfileFile.Type.CREDENTIALS).build()
        ).profileName("default").build();

        return credentialsProvider;
    }
```

Below is how I create the SQS client:

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    public SqsClient provideSqsClient(AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider) {
        return SqsClient.builder().credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .region(REGION).build();
    }
```

How can I allow the SQS client to refresh the credentials? Appreciate any help/guidance.

Comment: Not sure but commenting because I have the same problem due to an SSM automation that takes ~14 hours to complete.